# Delete non-matching data from table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a table and back-up of same table. After taking back-up inserted some data in the main table. Now I want to delete data from main table. How to achieve it?
Let say table is 'BookMap' with column AuthorID, BookName, BookID. Took backup of 'BookMap' table and inserted new data. Now want to delete this data.

**NOTE:** I don't have primary key here.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: You can use MERGE and WHEN MATCHED DELETE; Check here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: @scsimon: Merge statement need primary key

Comment: delete which data ? how do you want the tables to look like ? btw, why not have a primary key ?

Comment: @SandipPatel not if you check all columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `BookMap` to look just like the `backup_BookMap`, then you might consider:

```
truncate table bookmap;

insert into bookmap( . . .)
   select . . .
   from backup_bookmap;
```

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood you correctly, you want to delete data from you **non-backup** table, that have been inserted to **backup** table:

```
DELETE nonbackup
FROM BookMap as nonbackup
WHERE nonbackup.BookID IN
(
    SELECT BookID
    FROM BookMapBackup as backup
)
```

Comment: I think ur logic is incorrect. I cannot delete data only taking BookID as filter :(

Answer (score 1):

try like this,

```
DELETE B FROM bookmark B INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT *FROM (
select *From bookmark
except
select *From bookmarkbackup)T
)T1 ON T1.AuthorID=B.AuthorID
AND T1.BookName=B.BookName
AND T1.BookID=B.BookID
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is something you can test on:

```
DECLARE @book table
(
    AuthorID varchar,
    BookName varchar(255),
    BookID int
);

DECLARE @backupBook table
(
    AuthorID varchar,
    BookName varchar(255),
    BookID int
);

insert into @book values(1, 'book1', 1 )
insert into @book values(2, 'book2', 2 )
insert into @book values(3, 'book3', 3 )

insert into @backupBook values(1, 'book1', 1 )
insert into @backupBook values(2, 'book2', 2 )

select * from @book
select * from @backupBook

delete a
from @book a 
INNER JOIN @backupBook b
  ON a.AuthorID = b.AuthorID
  and a.BookName = b.BookName
  and a.BookID = b.BookID

select * from @book
select * from @backupBook
```

Comment: Inner join make so that you delete all rows that are found on both tables based on the inner join parameters

Comment: It will Delete all rows from Main table.

Comment: Dear user1926138 copy paste and try it ;)
Book 3 Remains in @book table while book 1 and 2 are removed